# 'Open' signs on commercial buildings - why are most of them red?

Tags: color-scheme

I am in the process of designing a nice OPEN sign, and I noticed that the vast majority of them are red. This seems bizarre to me, yet green open signs look odd. I just wondered if anybody knew why red seems to be the chosen colour.

To clarify, I am talking about an OPEN sign which will be placed in a sandwich board and stand outside a shop. But it can refer to any sign that indicates a retail establishment is open for business. I would also like to use the image on the website, though obviously in a smaller size, to be shown during the opening times.

Here is a for instance:

[image: Open sign]

If you Google "open sign" and look at the images, you will see that the most common colour is red. The green ones you see tend to be signs instructing you to push to open. The most common sign for open for business is red.

Comment: open what? the door of a moving car? bottle of pepsi? and the sign shows what? current state or action that'll happen if you press it?

Comment: Can you share an example?

Comment: I've made the question clearer and added an example. How do I flag this as no longer being on hold?

Comment: @DominicLloyd With the edit, this question still appears rather opinion-based, and thus is likely to remain closed.  Is there anything more specific, demonstrable, or actionable you want to know about the sign?

Comment: I think this question is clear. While there may be many opinions on why the majority of "Open" signs are red, I'm sure there are historical, cultural, and technical references that could provide definitive insight into the origin of the sign's color. Also, I believe he's asking if he should follow the trend and make his signs red instead of green which would meet most user's expectations even though red traditionally means stop/closed/danger in most North American traffic control contexts.

Comment: Brandon, you are quite right. If you google "open sign" and look at the images, you will see that the most common colour is red. The green ones you see tend to be signs instructing you to push to open. The most common sign for open for business is red. I really don't see how I can be any clearer than that.

Comment: @DominicLloyd maybe it underlines the [fortune and potential joy](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1517/the-favourite-question-icon-conveys-a-wrong-message?cb=1#comment3698_1517) from being a customer of such an establishment.

Comment: Red is the color for warning, alert and danger (yes also love, passions but not this context) People give red more attention then green.

Comment: Red/White are contrast and so are eye catching

Comment: This question might fare better on cogsci.SE

Comment: Well it certainly couldn't fare much worse. I had my office in stiches this morning when they asked how I had got on in my investigation.

Comment: I posted on Cogsci and got a very good answer within an hour, so thank you for the suggestion @RedSirius

http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/open-signs-on-commercial-buildings-why-are-most-of-them-red

Comment: "Stop" and come on in, we're open!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was cross posted and answered here: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/what-effect-does-the-colour-of-an-open-sign-have-on-peoples-behavior

Comment: Oh for heaven's sake. How is this question any more opinion based than something like this question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24255/responsive-web-design-what-should-happen-when-the-mobile-device-is-rotated

With regards to cross posting, I originally posted here but somebody advised me (rightly) that I would get a better response elsewhere. Quite frankly, I think that advice stands for any question on this particular section of Stack Exchange because it seems to be extremely over-policed and anything but a shining example of what a good user experience should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been thinking about this all day and then it kind of hit me.  This may sound simple and I have no scientific references or anything, but if you think in terms of a traffic light, you have green for go and red for stop.  Same with a stop sign.  So our brains are trained to stop when we encounter red lights and red signs.  So with that reasoning, I think the reason that so many *Come in we're open* signs are red is that your brain interprets that as:

[image: STOP!]

[image: Come in. We're OPEN!]

Answer (score 2):

The majority of the light that we see (and have evolved to be sensitive to) is in the cyan/green/chartreuse area of the visible spectrum.

[image: Sensitivity to visible light]

Even though we are sensitive to these colors, [habituation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habituation) causes us to not process ambient stimuli containing them (just like how we don't process the sound of a fan in our room). However, our eye will be drawn to man-made objects that capitalize on the colors on the far sides of this spectrum (think of how well neon red & blue open signs grab your attention regardless of the ambient light).

All of this is totally dependent on the environment, though. If you're in some kind of district that is lit with red light, a green light will probably grab your attention.